# Change CSS for ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to change design of `ActionLink` below.

Please help me!

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.purchaseId })
```

Comment: Please provide more details about what you want to change. Also, do let us know what you have tried so far

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", null, new{id=Model.purchaseId, @class="mycssclass"})
```

The overload you used has "routeValues" as 3rd parameter. My version ignores that and adds a 4th parameter for htmlAttributes.

Also, when you want to use reserved words (such as `class`) as properties, you can escape them with an `@`.

See the various overloads on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink.aspx).